# BlueMix: Unable to import updated sklearn into iPython

Tags: python, pip, scikit-learn, ibm-cloud

I am running an ipython notebook on IBM BlueMix and the default version of sklearn is version 0.11 -- I want to upgrade to sklearn-0.18.

Edit: I meant I want to upgrade to sklearn-0.17.

```
import sklearn
print sklearn.__version__

​0.11
```

The BlueMix docs say to use:

```
!pip install -U --user sklearn
```

Here is the output:

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: sklearn in /gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Collecting scikit-learn (from sklearn)
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.17.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.11
```

That didn't seem to work. Maybe it has something to do with the old version of pip...

```
!pip install --upgrade --user pip


You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-7.1.0


import pip
print pip.__version__

7.1.0
```

Ok, so it's not just sklearn. The problem seems to be that somehow upgraded packages are not being installed in the correct path.

After some sleuthing, I find:

```
!ls -al ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

total 0
drwx------  8 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 18:06 .
drwx------  3 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 15:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 15:46 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 15:53 pip-8.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 18:40 pip-8.0.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 18:06 scikit_learn-0.17-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x 25 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 18:06 sklearn
drwxr-xr-x  2 s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed users 4096 Jan 22 15:48 sklearn-0.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

So, let's try this...

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/gpfs/fs01/user/s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')

reload(sklearn)
print sklearn.__version__

​0.17
```

Now, it looks like version is correct, so try to import some of the new functions from sklearn-0.17.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-8985e3efac9f> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

ImportError: cannot import name roc_auc_score
```

I get the same error with anything that is supposed to be in version 0.17. It seems like python is referencing the old sklearn version 0.11 when trying to import.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider using virtualenv?

Comment: Yes... reluctantly. I'd rather not go through the entire process of configuring a new environment, but I suppose I probably need to have a script for that anyways... so , it may be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

BlueMix seems to initialize the iPython environment to sklearn-0.11  every time I login. Apparently, once I have imported sklearn verison 0.11, reloading sklearn with the new path for version 0.17 does not change anything.

I needed to modify the path to point at version 0.17 before doing the initial import and then the initial import will reference the updated version, like so...

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/gpfs/fs01/user/s3b2-519e0ce881616c-546ab68fb1ed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')

import sklearn
print sklearn.__version__

0.17
```

Now, I can successfully do the following without errors:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```